# using a variable as a directory path to redirect output in bash

Tags: bash, file, variables, io-redirection

I am trying to write a script that will allow the user to input the path of the directory to which they want to store a file. I have something that looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter the directory path"
read varpath
varfile="Filename"
echo "This is a file" > "$varpath$varfile"
```

what I want is a file in the directory path the user entered called "Filename" and has the line "This is a file" However, I am getting an error saying that there is not such file or directory. Can someone tell me whats wrong, or if there's an alternate solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `"$varpath/$varfile"`

Comment: Depends entirely on what the user inputs. If `varpath` is `a` then this code would create `aFilename` in the current directory with no errors (assuming you have write permission and the disk is not full, etc). If the user inputs a path containing directories which do not exist, then yes, predictably, there will be an error, because the shell will not spontaneously create those directories. (But your code could, and it would not be a lot more complex. Hint: `mkdir -p $(dirname "$varpath")` if `varpath` is not itself a directory.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proabably you need a `/`.

```
echo "This is a file" > "${varpath}/${varfile}"
```

You can also `echo` the variables to make sure they are correct

Comment: Hi, I have tried what you said... and its still giving me the same error, I even tried to echo the path name and from the looks of it, it is a correct name.

Comment: @user3351901: Make sure the path is correct. Try `ls ${varpath}/${varfile}` in the script and see if it prints the desired file.

Comment: Yeup. Thanks i got it!

Answer (score 0):

Few things you might want to handle:

1. The user input directory has the required folders, if not create them using `mkdir -p` command.
2. The user enters dir path that either ends with / or not. If not, you might want to add it yourself.